# Given a differentiable function and $f'(n) = m$, find $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm working on an assignment, and I have no clue how to tackle this question,

Given the function $f(x)$ is differentiable, and $f'(4) = 3$, find the value of $f'(\sqrt{x})$ when $x = 4$.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this, I'm guessing that there is more to this than just finding a function that holds true for the case $f'(4) = 3$ then plugging in $\sqrt{4} / 2$ into it and getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try using the chain rule. To see why one might use it, note that you have composed $f$ with the square root function. Any time you see function compositions in calculus, your mind should automatically jump to chain rule.

Comment: What is being composed with the square root in $f'(\sqrt x)$ is not $f$ but $f'$. Since $f$ is being derived _before_ composing it with the square root, there is no use for the chain rule here.

Comment: I think it is a typo as you suggest. It happens a lot with newish posters. It seems to be horrifically misquoted but I think it is a chain rule question based on the presence of the square root. I'll leave it as is until the OP edits the post.

Comment: Even the title post seems to be confused..

Answer (score 0):

Either you've quoted the exercise wrong, or you don't have enough information to find the required value.

In order to evaluate $f'(\sqrt x)$ when $x=4$ you need to know $f'(2)$ not $f'(4)$ because

$$ f'(\sqrt x)=f'(\sqrt 4)=f'(2) $$

Even if what you're being asked for isn't $f'(\sqrt x)$ but $\frac{d}{dx} f(\sqrt x)$, what you need is still $f'(2)$ (together with the chain rule).

Comment: I did misquote the question, it's $\frac{d}{dx}$f(\sqrt{x}), other than that I included all of the information. Also, is there a difference between writing $f'(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$? Thanks

Comment: @user1327636 There is a big difference in the case of function composition. $f'(\sqrt{x})$ means evaluate the derivative of $f$ AT $\sqrt{x}$. $(f(\sqrt{x}))'$ means to take the derivative of the function $f(\sqrt{x})$